# javascript progressive counter

Tags: javascript, counter

yesterday i found a nice effect on some website wich i decided to implement on my projects, its a simple javascript progressive counter, it will look something like this

[image]

obviously it starts from 0 to X without looping and looks more smoother in live web, anyway, i could not find a third party snipet, **how i can achieve this!?**

Comment: so... what's the question?

Comment: instead of make a question and wait for a reply, i decided solve this and share.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  it's not a question

Comment: i hate you guys!!, some months ago i asked something and was downvoted, why !? why "i dont realize any effort to solve my own question", now i solved my own question and is downvoted again. dumb logic*.

Answer (score 0):

**progressive-counter.js**

```
progressiveCounter=function(params) {

    /*

    autor:

    some eccentric money maker <3

    usage:

    give a progressive transition effect to a counter who starts from X to Y

    params:

    id                  ~   string      ~   to identify internally the counter
    container           ~   object      ~   where the result will be displayed
    from                ~   int         ~   number to start
    dest                ~   int         ~   optional, number to end
    destFromProperty    ~   string      ~   optional, data defined with "data-" on "container" to specify number to end
    format              ~   function    ~   callback to be used to format the output
    finished            ~   function    ~   callback to be used at the end of iteration

    note:

    code made by another snipet of code found on some site, my thanks to original coders by the idea, all you need is share :*

    */

    // ...

    if(typeof(progressiveCounter_data)=="undefined")
    progressiveCounter_data={};

    // ...

    if( (typeof(params.id)!="string" || typeof(params.id)=="")
        || typeof(params.container)!="object"
        || (typeof(params.dest)=="undefined" && typeof(params.destFromProperty)=="undefined")   )
    return;

    // ...

    params.from=parseInt(params.from,10);

    if(typeof(params.from)!="number")
    return;

    if(params.destFromProperty)
    params.dest=$(params.container).data(params.destFromProperty);

    params.dest=parseInt(params.dest,10);

    if(typeof(params.dest)!="number")
    return;

    if(params.from>params.dest)
    return;

    if(typeof(params.format)!="function")
    params.format=null;

    if(typeof(params.finished)!="function")
    params.finished=null;

    // ...

    progressiveCounter_data[params.id]={

        container:params.container,
        from:params.from,
        dest:params.dest,
        shrsCounterTimestep:10,
        format:params.format,
        finished:params.finished

    };

    // ...

    progressiveCounter_iterate(params.id);

}

progressiveCounter_iterate=function(id) {

    // ...

    if(typeof(progressiveCounter_data)=="undefined" || typeof(progressiveCounter_data[id])!="object")
    return;

    // ...

    var data=progressiveCounter_data[id];

    // ...

    var delta=data.dest-data.from,
        threshold=15,
        lastThreshold=4,
        timestepIncrement=15,
        numberFormatted=""
        ;

    // ...

    if(delta<threshold)
    data.shrsCounterTimestep+=timestepIncrement;

    delta=Math.ceil(delta*0.05);

    if(data.from>=data.dest-lastThreshold){

        delta=1;
        data.shrsCounterTimestep=350;

    }

    data.from+=delta;

    // ...

    if(data.format)
    numberFormatted=data.format(data.from);
    else
    numberFormatted=data.from;

    // ...

    if(data.from>=data.dest){

        data.from=data.dest;
        $(data.container).text(numberFormatted);

        if(data.finished)
        data.finished();

    }
    else {

        $(data.container).text(numberFormatted);
        setTimeout(function() { progressiveCounter_iterate(id); },data.shrsCounterTimestep);

    }

};
```

**basic usage**

```
progressiveCounter({

    id:"stats_visits",
    container:$("#element").get(0),
    from:0,
    dest:43800

});
```